# Deployment from bitbucket to azure using nuget fails

Tags: azure, nuget, bitbucket

I'm using **NancyFX** and I added it to my solution via **Nuget**.
When I publish the solution to Azure, the solution is compiled and the nancy dlls goes to Azure without problem. 
I am also a **Bitbucket** user, so I give a try to the continuos deployment, but the problem arises because no `Nancy.dll` is on the server.

Do I need to push the bin dlls to bitbucket?

Can Azure use the **Nuget** package information to download the external refs?

Comment: Do you have package restore turned on? Azure websites should restore your packages when you're building.

Comment: Thanks Pranav. This seems to be the correct path, but I still did´t achive the goal... :-) The problem now is that Azure don´t find de nuget.exe, I have uploade it by ftp, because the .exe files are ignored by git, but Azure can´t find it.

Comment: You'll either have to check in NuGet.exe in to the .nuget directory or set the `DownloadNuGetExe` flag in your NuGet.targets to true. Try getting your repo to a state where you can build a clean repo with package restore turned on locally.

Comment: @AlbertoBasalo - did you solve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Hi, @GeorgePhilip I tried for a couple o days but I didn´t solved, so now I´m publishing right from VS to Azure.

Comment: I am trying to get to the bottom of this and is making some good progress. I will try to post a response as soon as I account for all the possibilities.